# Is possible to get rid of group by loop for each owner

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects of class NameOwnersBasedOnRule with properties Name, Rule and Owner:

```
var nameOwnersBasedOnRule = new List<NameOwnersBasedOnRule>
    {
        new NameOwnersBasedOnRule { Name = "Name1", Rule = "Rule1", Owner = "Owner1"},
        new NameOwnersBasedOnRule { Name = "Name1", Rule = "Rule2", Owner = "Owner2"},
        new NameOwnersBasedOnRule { Name = "Name1", Rule = "Rule3", Owner = "Owner3"},

        new NameOwnersBasedOnRule { Name = "Name2", Rule = "Rule2", Owner = "Owner2"},

        new NameOwnersBasedOnRule { Name = "Name3", Rule = "Rule1", Owner = "Owner1"},
        new NameOwnersBasedOnRule { Name = "Name3", Rule = "Rule1", Owner = "Owner2"},
        new NameOwnersBasedOnRule { Name = "Name3", Rule = "Rule1", Owner = "Owner3"}
    };
```

Then I have a below dataPacket with Rules and multiple instances (InstanceName1, InstanceName2) of InstanceData having Name,

```
 var dataPacket = new Packet
    {
        Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
        Rules = new List<string> { "Rule1", "Rule2" },
        Results = new Result
        {
            ResultName = "ResultName1",
            Instances = new List<Instance>
            {
                new Instance
                {
                    InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                    InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                    {
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V1"},
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V2"},
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"},
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name4", Value = "V4"}
                    }
                },
                new Instance
                {
                    InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                    InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                    {
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V5"},
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V6"},
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"},
                        new InstanceData{Name = "Name4", Value = "V8"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

- I need to prepare and split InstanceData to each owner based on Name and Rule match...
- Both instance of Name1 should be distributed to Owner1 and Owner2.
- Both instance of Name2 only to Owner2.
- Both instance of Name3 to all owners Owner1, Owner2, Owner3
- Both instance of 'Name4 to NONE as no match of Name/Rule with any owner with master listnameOwnersBasedOnRule`.

Below is expected output I am looking for,

```
var owner1Data = new Packet
            {
                Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
                Results = new Result
                {
                    ResultName = "ResultName1",
                    Instances = new List<Instance>
                    {
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V1"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"}
                            }
                        },
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V5"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var owner2Data = new Packet
            {
                Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
                Results = new Result
                {
                    ResultName = "ResultName1",
                    Instances = new List<Instance>
                    {
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V1"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V2"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"}
                            }
                        },
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V5"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V6"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"},
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var owner3Data = new Packet
            {
                Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
                Results = new Result
                {
                    ResultName = "ResultName1",
                    Instances = new List<Instance>
                    {
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"}
                            }
                        },
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Here is my C# LINQ query query to get above desired result,

```
var test = (from grp in nameOwnersBasedOnRule.GroupBy(x => x.Owner)
                            //filter Name here based on rule matched        
                        let result1 = grp.Where(item1 => dataPacket.Rules.Contains(item1.Rule)).Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList()
                        select new
                        {
                            Application = grp.Key,
                            Data = new Packet
                            {
                                Id = dataPacket.Id,
                                Results = new Result
                                {
                                    ResultName = dataPacket.Results.ResultName,
                                    Instances = dataPacket.Results.Instances
                                        //result1 used here
                                        .Where(item => item.InstanceDatas.Any(data => result1.Contains(data.Name)))
                                        .Select(item => new Instance
                                        {
                                            InstanceName = item.InstanceName,
                                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>(item.InstanceDatas
                                                //result1 used here as well
                                                .Where(data => result1.Contains(data.Name))
                                                .Select(data => new InstanceData
                                                {
                                                    Name = data.Name,
                                                    Value = data.Value
                                                }))
                                        }).ToList()
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

**Here I am doing group by on Owner and for each owner I am validating same packet again and again to get desired results for a owner. Can I improve this to avoid group by loop or any other better way? Please suggest!**

Here is my all class structures used for below question,

```
public class NameOwnersBasedOnRule
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Rule { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
    }

    public class Packet
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Rules { get; set; }
        public Result Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string ResultName { get; set; }
        public List<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
    }

    public class Instance
    {
        public string InstanceName { get; set; }
        public List<InstanceData> InstanceDatas { get; set; }
    }

    public class InstanceData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Most of the code in this question appears to be hypothetical and that makes the question off-topic for Code Review. Please see the [Code Review guidelines for asking good questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

**.NET Collections is your friend**

> NOTE: My sample code is intended to show the idea of the thing, not be ready-to-compile code using all those classes you created.  My spider-sense tells me they're not all necessary.

A custom collection *will* solve your problems.  Inherit or compose with, say `List` and use the many functions that take expressions (technically `Predicate`) that tell the collection how to `Find`, `Sort`, compare, etc.

The takeaway is that there is lots of magic built into .NET collection classes. The effort is very worth it. Your custom collection code will be amazingly simple. The client code will be unbelievably clean, clear, and simple.

```
public class RuleOwners {
   protected List< NameOwnersBasedOnRule > Owners { get; set; }

   public NameOwnersBasedOnRule FindByName(string theName) {
      return Owners.Find( x => x.Name = theName );
   }
}
```

Of course you can return a filtered `RuleOwners` collection.

Of course there is `Sort` that also takes an expression. If you override `CompareTo` then `RuleOwners.Sort()` (no parameter) automatically sorts according to your custom `CompartTo` - a default sort.

---

Here's a notion of how adding to the collection might work. NOTE::: First, use constructors to make `NameOwnersBasedOnRule` objects. Next, `List.Contains` uses `NameOwnersBasedOnRule.Equals` in the background. You must override `NameOwnersBasedOnRule.Equals` - here we assume `Equals` was overridden and I've arbitrarily decided objects are equal by Name.

```
public class RuleOwners {
   protected List< NameOwnersBasedOnRule > Owners { get; set; }

   public bool Add ( InstanceData rawData ) {
      if (rawData = null) return;

      NameOwnersBasedOnRule newGuy = new NameOwnersBasedOnRule(rawData);

      if (Owners.Contains(newGuy)) {
          // add rawData.Rules to existing object.
      } else {
        Owners.Add( newGuy);
      }
   }
}
```

NOTE: I don't use inheritance because I want to control what functionality is exposed, and only the intended custom behavior. Otherwise client code can use every public `List` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @radarbob. Mostly I didn't get how my `dataPacket ` works with custom collection. How to split and prepare data for each owner. If you can further put some code and on how to use, that will be helpful. Appreciate!

Comment: Your classes are incomprehensible. What are they for? What are they supposed to do? Classes are about what they do. A class with no methods, i.e. no functionality is pointless. The point of collection classes is to put "collection" functionality where it belongs. How to select (or find, group, add, delete, count, etc) `Packets`, for example should be in a `Packets` collection. My examples show how simple that can be.

Comment: *... how ... `dataPacket` works with [other classes]*.  Given a `Packet` class with appropriate Packet methods - ditto for all your classes - then it is obvious how to create them,  what can be done with/to them. Writing interactive code is simply a matter of using the API's - the class' public methods. Your code is the opposite of that.  Class specific, collection specific, and interactive code is all mixed together. There simply is nothing there that we can make sense of and determine what your post is asking.